# select specific column from pandas MultiIndex dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a MultiIndex dataframe with 200 columns. I would like to select a specific column from that. Suppose df is some part of my dataframe:

```
df=
                       a                             b
                       l       h     l       h       l       h      l    
                      cold    hot    hot    cold    cold     hot   hot
2009-01-01 01:00:00   0.1     0.9    0.4    0.29    0.15     0.6    0.3
2009-01-01 02:00:00   0.1     0.8    0.35   0.2     0.15     0.6    0.4
2009-01-01 03:00:00   0.12    0.7    0.3    0.23    0.23     0.8    0.3
2009-01-01 04:00:00   0.1     0.9    0.33   0.24    0.15     0.6    0.4
2009-01-01 05:00:00   0.17    0.9    0.41   0.23    0.18     0.75   0.4
```

I would like to select the values for this column[h,hot].

My output should be:

```
df['h','hot']=
                       a      b
2009-01-01 01:00:00   0.9   0.6
2009-01-01 02:00:00   0.8   0.6
2009-01-01 03:00:00   0.7   0.8
2009-01-01 04:00:00   0.9   0.6
2009-01-01 05:00:00   0.9   0.75
```

I would appreciate any guidance on how I could select that.

Comment: I think that `df['b','h','hot']` should just work here for hierarchical columns

Comment: Please post `list(df.columns)`. This will help us see if there are errant spaces...

Comment: `df['b','h','hot']` works for me, if it doesn't then post `df.info()` and `print(df.columns.tolist()` to see what the real column names are

Comment: Thank you for your answers. But I had forgotten a minor point of my question. I modified my post a bit. I do appreciate that if you guide me with the modified version of my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For multi-index slicing as you desire the columns needs to be sorted first using `sort_index(axis=1)`, you can then select the cols of interest without error:

```
In [12]:
df = df.sort_index(axis=1)
df['a','h','hot']

Out[12]:
0
2009-01-01 01:00:00    0.9
2009-01-01 02:00:00    0.8
2009-01-01 03:00:00    0.7
2009-01-01 04:00:00    0.9
2009-01-01 05:00:00    0.9
Name: (a, h, hot), dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes, that's what exactly I was looking for. I had tried this commands without "sort", and as you said I got that error. Could you please guide me what exactly does that "sort" command? Thank you.

Comment: `sort_values` just sorts the columns in this case, it's a method on `Index`, `Series`, `DataFrame` etc

Comment: Thank you. But "sort_values" leads to sort column names without moving their values (wrong label).That means when I am looking for values of df['a','h','hot'], I will got another values for example df['a','l','cold']. I do appreciate that if you guide me to solve this issue.

Comment: does `df = df.sort_index(axis=1)` work prior to the column selection?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dataframe= pd.DataFrame()
dataframe["temp"] = df["b"]["h"]["hot"]
```

df - is your dataframe